# how to use float32 multiarray message

Tags: ros, multiarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is a very noob question. How can i specify the size of the message, for example i want to send an array of 1x6. I see the layout, it has the size field but no field to specify the rows and columns

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226022/how-to-use-float32-multiarray-message/) by [minh221193](https://answers.ros.org/users/25873/minh221193/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [How to initialize a UInt8MultiArray message](http://answers.ros.org/question/37185/how-to-initialize-a-uint8multiarray-message/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1